# ng-if in tr-element if applicable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i have this table which i render by iterating a list of objects with ng-repeat. I also have the ability to do some filtering on a pre defined set of strings by listing them in a  element together with ng-model and having the user select from the list. Then together with my ng-repeat i have a ng-if to only show those objects that passes the filter. However, i also want the ability to disable the filter altogether and list all objects at once, this is where my ng-if messes it up.

Example data:

```
[
  {
    "key": "val A"
  },
  {
    "key": "val B"
  },
  {
    "key": "val A"
  }
]
```

HTML Code:

```
<!-- List of strings to filter on -->
<select ng-model="keyFilter">
    <option>Val A</option>
    <option>Val B</option>
</select>

<!-- List objects in table -->
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="object in objects"
            ng-if="object.key == keyFilter">
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end>
            <!-- Expandable inline table -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get this to work, when i select 'Val A' or 'Val B' in the set of options the table updates and show only those objects. However, i don't really know how to get all objects to show at once. I would like to have a initial check before the ng-if on whether 'keyFilter' is null or not. That is, if the filter is applicable.

Comment: have you tried `ng-repeat-start="object in objects | filter:keyFilter"` without `ng-if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`ng-if="object.key == keyFilter"`

to

`ng-if="object.key === keyFilter || !keyFilter"`

That way, if there is no keyFilter (`!keyFilter`) all the data will show.